# Turning remove_if into remove_not_if

Tags: c++, stl, predicates, remove-if

How can I reverse a predicate's return value, and remove the elements that return false instead of true?

Here is my code:

```
headerList.remove_if(FindName(name));
```

(please ignore lack of erase)

with FindName a simple functor:

```
struct FindName
{
    CString m_NameToFind;

    FindInspectionNames(const CString &nameToFind)
    {
        m_NameToFind = nameToFind;
    }

    bool operator()(const CHeader &header)
    {
        if(header.Name == m_NameToFind)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
};
```

I would like something like:

```
list.remove_if(FindName(name) == false);
```

Not yet using c++0x, so lambdas not allowed, sadly.  I'm hoping there is a nicer solution than writing a NotFindName functor.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check [`not1`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not1) in the `<functional>` header:

```
headerList.remove_if( std::not1( FindName( name ) ) );
```

Oh, and this:

```
if(header.Name == m_NameToFind)
{
    return true;
}

return false;
```

*Please* don't do that.

```
return ( header.Name == m_NameToFind );
```

That's *much* better, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks, it works with the following mods:

Functor needs to inherit from std::unary_function<CHeader, bool>

operator() needs to be a const member function

Comment: Actually inheritance is not necessary, but you need to define the proper typedef that it gives you for free. As for the `const`-ness, it goes without saying :)

Answer (score 3):

alternatively you could use boost bind so you don't have to write that unary_function struct:

```
bool header_has_name (const CHeader& h, const CString& n) {return h.name == n;}

headerList.remove_if (boost::bind (header_has_name, _1, "name"));
```

and for remove_if_not:

```
headerList.remove_if (!boost::bind (header_has_name, _1, "name"));
```

You could even use std::equal() to avoid the header_has_name function completely but at that point it becomes a little bit ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I think writing a NotFindName functor is your best bet.